# Dice Stack - Find a random question

Tags: app, random

## [DiceStack website](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/)

<sup>([www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/))</sup>

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

### About

Fetches a random question from a Stack Exchange site of your choice.

#### License

Free-to-use webapp. Source not available.

#### Features

- Ability to filter by tags, score and answer status

#### Contact

My [email address is on my website](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/contact/).

Comment: awesome, we always get requests for "show me a random question!" I might suggest having a minimum threshold of votes/views to ensure you don't get total junk Qs though

Comment: Bou how can I access that application?

Comment: @chanchal1987: Click the link at the top of the page.

Comment: Seems to have disappeared. I get an empty white screen.

Comment: @TRiG: I guess I need to update it to use the latest API version.

Comment: I use your app to look for low quality posts that need cleanup that have gone undetected.  Can you bring back the filter that lets me specify a range of votes.  So I can select: -20 to 0 ?

Answer (score 8):

Hey Simon.

Interesting idea but, in my opinion, given the vast array of topics, for something like this to be engaging you will need to provide a tag selector at the least.

Maintaining a local index of tags, updated daily perhaps, to feed a work-alike tag selector as available on SE sites would be my next step.

Comment: I've added the ability to filter by tags, but decided against auto-completion. As I don't like the idea of regularly going through every page of tags on every site and calling the API as the user types would be slow and hog resources.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the HTML entities are escaped, in the results. Can this be fixed?

> [image: Entity text in results]

Answer (score 4):

I'd love it to bring up `x` questions. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend filtering by answered/unanswered as a very useful first filter option.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest giving a list of 10/15/20 questions instead of redirecting.

Now I click "Go", wait until the question is loaded and if its not satisfactory I need to go back, click "Go", ... Quite a lengthy process (about 5-6 s). If submitting just gave me a list of 10/15/20 question, I could

1. read the titles first,
2. open the questions I'm interested in in new tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be practical, since it would use the API very heavily.

Answer (score 1):

Another feature that could be useful is to ignore some tags. That would help in not getting unwanted questions in sites such as SO.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to bring up closed questions as well as questions that have been migrated off the site.